# Why are some Firestore document values null when called from a FirestoreRecyclerAdapter? (No setter/field for ... found on class)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection of purchases, with document values for companyId, storeId, value, timestamp, and purchaseId. I am trying to call these in a FirestoreRecyclerAdapter in order to display a list of receipts.

My problem is that some of the document values (companyId, storId, purchaseId) are returning null, while some (timestamp, value) are returning the value as required.

The log says that for these values that return null, there is no setter/field for it on the class Receipt. I've been trying to find answers for this on Stackexchange but I can't find one that is relevant. The closest I have found is that the class type the value is initiated in the class Receipt doesn't match the type from the database, but I double checked and they are strings in both cases.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Here is the Firestore structure:

[image: Firestore Image]

I have a Receipt class:

```
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp;

public class Receipt {
    private String companyId, purchaseId, storeId, value;
    Timestamp timestamp;

    public Receipt() {
    }

    public Receipt(String companyId, String purchaseId, String storeId, Timestamp timestamp, String value) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
        this.purchaseId = purchaseId;
        this.storeId = storeId;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setCompany(String companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    public String getPurchase() {
        return purchaseId;
    }

    public void setPurchase(String purchaseId) {
        this.purchaseId = purchaseId;
    }

    public String getStore() {
        return storeId;
    }

    public void setStore(String storeId) {
        this.storeId = storeId;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

There is a DisplayReceiptsViewHolder:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4.R;

public class DisplayReceiptsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView date, company, amount;
    public Button viewReceiptButton;
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public DisplayReceiptsViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receipt_list_date_tv);
        company = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receipt_list_company_tv);
        amount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receipt_list_amount_tv);
        viewReceiptButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_receipt_list_btn);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //itemClickListener.onItemClick(v, v, getAdapterPosition(), false);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }
}
```

And then in the DisplayReceiptsActivity I am just retrieving the values for now and logging them to the console:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4.Models.Receipt;
import com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4.ViewHolders.DisplayReceiptsViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;


public class DisplayReceiptsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Receipt, DisplayReceiptsViewHolder> receiptAdapter;

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_receipts);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.display_receipt_list);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        Query receiptsQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("Users")
                .document(currentUser.getUid())
                .collection("Purchases");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Receipt> receiptOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Receipt>()
                .setQuery(receiptsQuery, Receipt.class)
                .build();

        receiptAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Receipt, DisplayReceiptsViewHolder>(receiptOptions) {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DisplayReceiptsViewHolder displayReceiptsViewHolder,
                                        int i,
                                        @NonNull Receipt receipt) {

                String company = receipt.getCompany();
                displayReceiptsViewHolder.company.setText(company);
                Log.d("TESTING", "Company = " + company);

                String purchaseId = receipt.getPurchase();
                Log.d("TESTING", "Purchase = " + purchaseId);

                String storeId = receipt.getStore();
                Log.d("TESTING", "Store = " + storeId);

                Timestamp timestamp = receipt.getTimestamp();
                displayReceiptsViewHolder.date.setText(timestamp.toString());
                Log.d("TESTING", "Timestamp = " + timestamp);

                String value = receipt.getValue();
                displayReceiptsViewHolder.amount.setText(value);
                Log.d("TESTING", "Value = " + value);
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public DisplayReceiptsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.receipt_list_item,
                    parent,
                    false);
                return new DisplayReceiptsViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(receiptAdapter);
        receiptAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        receiptAdapter.stopListening();
    }

    public void returnHome(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayReceiptsActivity.this, ShopHomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayReceiptsActivity.this, ShopHomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Here is a copy of the log:

```
2021-12-23 15:48:56.330 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for companyId found on class com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4.Models.Receipt
2021-12-23 15:48:56.330 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for purchaseId found on class com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4.Models.Receipt
2021-12-23 15:48:56.330 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for storeId found on class com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4.Models.Receipt
2021-12-23 15:48:56.331 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 D/TESTING: Company = null
2021-12-23 15:48:56.331 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 D/TESTING: Purchase = null
2021-12-23 15:48:56.331 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 D/TESTING: Store = null
2021-12-23 15:48:56.332 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 D/TESTING: Timestamp = Timestamp(seconds=1640270467, nanoseconds=629000000)
2021-12-23 15:48:56.332 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 D/TESTING: Value = 0.75
2021-12-23 15:48:56.358 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for companyId found on class com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4.Models.Receipt
2021-12-23 15:48:56.358 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for purchaseId found on class com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4.Models.Receipt
2021-12-23 15:48:56.359 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for storeId found on class com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4.Models.Receipt
2021-12-23 15:48:56.359 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 D/TESTING: Company = null
2021-12-23 15:48:56.360 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 D/TESTING: Purchase = null
2021-12-23 15:48:56.360 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 D/TESTING: Store = null
2021-12-23 15:48:56.360 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 D/TESTING: Timestamp = Timestamp(seconds=1640273317, nanoseconds=835000000)
2021-12-23 15:48:56.360 2462-2462/com.dummies.rbncr.tapaidhscanner4 D/TESTING: Value = 0.75
```

Answer (score 1):

OK - so I have fixed the problem by editing the names of the getters and setters in the Receipt class to be identical to the variable names. I'm not sure why this workd but it did:

```
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp;

public class Receipt {
    private String companyId, purchaseId, storeId, value;
    Timestamp timestamp;

    public Receipt() {
    }

    public Receipt(String companyId, String purchaseId, String storeId, Timestamp timestamp, String value) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
        this.purchaseId = purchaseId;
        this.storeId = storeId;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    // updated from getCompany()
    public String getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }
    
    // updated from setCompany(String companyId)
    public void setCompanyId(String companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    // updated from getPurchase()
    public String getPurchaseId() {
        return purchaseId;
    }

    // updated from setPurchase(String purchaseId)
    public void setPurchaseId(String purchaseId) {
        this.purchaseId = purchaseId;
    }

    // updated from setStore()
    public String getStoreId() {
        return storeId;
    }

    // updated from setStore(String storeId)
    public void setStoreId(String storeId) {
        this.storeId = storeId;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Firebase uses the getters and setters to determine the property names, based on the [JavaBean naming conventions](https://www.google.com/search?q=javabean+naming+conventions). These pseudo-properties determine the public contract for your `Receipt` class, rather than the private/non-public fields. Alternatively, you can define `public` fields and no getters/setters, and Firestore will then use the public fields to map the data from/to the database.